# jstree - ie9 briefly expands and then collapses the tree on page refresh

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, jstree

I'm loading the tree from a UL and in Firefox or Chrome, a page refresh is fine. But in IE9 there is a brief (and ugly) expansion of the entire tree before it is collapsed back to how it should be. It's a tenth of a second or whatever, but it's a show-stopper for the project.

Any advice on how to prevent this behaviour will be much appreciated. 
Doctype html 4.01. Jsquery min 1.7.2. Jstree 1.0. Code below.

```
$(function(){
$("#treeview").jstree({
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "default",
        "dots" : false,
        "icons" : false
    },
    "ui" : {
            "selected_parent_close" : "false",
            "select_multiple_modifier" : "false",
            "initially_select" : [$('body').attr('id')],
    },
    "core": { 
                "animation": 500
            },
    "cookies" : {
                "save_selected" : false
                }, 
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui", "cookies" ]

});
$("#treeview").bind("reselect.jstree", function () {
    $("#treeview").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        document.location = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
    });
}); 
$("#treeview").bind("loaded.jstree", function () {
    $("#treeview").jstree("open_all", "#" + $('body').attr('id'));
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Hide the tree first using display: none in your div

```
<div id="myJsTree" style="display: none">

</div>
```

After this in your jquery once you apply jstree to your div, make the tree visible

```
$("#myJsTree").jstree({
    // set tree parameters here ...
}).show();
```